# How to download Launchpad ppa repositories on an android device to be installed on an airgapped ubuntu system

Tags: android, ubuntu, gis, gdal

I have a completely air-gapped  system. how can I download this(https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages) repository on my android device so i can run the install command for gdal-bin

```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
```

I need to do this because I am trying to run the command

```
gdalbuildvrt somegeotiff.vrt * .tif
```

but it says command not found, but can be installed with :

```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
```

to finish a vts-geospatial project.

Comment: I have figured out the problem

Answer (score 0):

follow the steps on this answer here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/618242/how-can-i-download-deb-from-a-ppa)

Beware: this does not download any dependencies, and you will still need to download the dependencies if you are downloading .deb files separately.

to counter this, you can search for and download them right on http://packages.ubuntu.com/ to a folder and then run sudo in the terminal